# How to determine whether the field is selected or not in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some code that lists out items in a table from a database. The click function toggles the cells between green and red.

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in Pool">
  <td ng-class="{'btn-danger': namestarted[$index],
                'btn-success': !namestarted[$index]}"
      ng-click="changeColor(team.chrTeamName, $index)">{{ team.chrTeamName }}</td>
  <td>{{ team.intSeed }}</td>
  <td ng-class="{'btn-danger': divstarted[$index],
                'btn-success': !divstarted[$index]}"
      ng-click="changeColor(team.chrDivision, $index)">{{ team.chrDivision }}</td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.namestarted = [];
$scope.divstarted = [];
$scope.changeColor= function (status, index) {
  if(status == "Name"){
    //How to know if the 'Name" is Selected or NotSelected???
    $scope.namestarted [index] = !$scope.namestarted [index];}
  else
    $scope.divstarted [index] = !$scope.divstarted [index];
}
```

Now when i click "Name" or "Division", i need to know whether it is Selected or NotSelected (active or not)??

Comment: Pass `team` to the `changeColor()` function to check the stattus

Comment: What is the current specific problem or question? You have shown some code but not given any clues as to what works or doesn't or any errors it produces. See [ask]

Comment: Charlie: The code works great but when i click ChangeColor() the i need to be able to catch the status whether its selected or not??

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the following pluker link...It will give you a better idea

https://plnkr.co/edit/9GbNn2RTSsdeiKZZjt0T?p=preview

```
$scope.setSelected = function(idSelectedVote) {
   $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
}

<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="setSelected(vote.id)" ng-class="{selected : vote.id === idSelectedVote}">
        <li  class="created">
          {{vote.created|date}}
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            {{vote.ip}}
        </li>
        <li class="status">
            {{vote.status}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```